# Tabbar delegate is not getting called

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I am trying to capture the event each time a tab bar button is pressed and have added  `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in the `AppDelegate.h` the below function to `AppDelegate.m` file but its not getting called. I have also connected `tabBarController` delegate to First Responder in the IB

Could anyone here help me fix this problem for me please?

//  AppDelegate.h

`@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

//  AppDelegate.m

```
    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

   NSLog(@"Touched Tab\n");

}
```

[image]

Comment: don't bind First responer with delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it needed was two lines in the below function to make the delegate work. Hope it saves time and frustration for someone.

// AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
  self.m_pTabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  self.m_pTabBarController.delegate = self;
  return YES;
```

}

// AppDelegate.h

```
@interface ftAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
IBOutlet UITabBarController *m_pTabBarController;
```

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *m_pTabBarController;

@end

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your graphic correctly, your "delegate" should not be the "first responder" (who knows what that is set to; it might be the view controller or it might be a keyboard or basically it's whatever object is set to be the first responder... ).

Instead, you need to set the delegate to be the object or class (your view controller?) where the delegate method you've coded up actually lives.  Looks like the delegate should be set to your "`AppDelegate`" object.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please bind your delegate with AppDelegate instead of the FirstResponder.

Comment: He's using a storyboard.  The App Delegate placeholder is not available in a storyboard.

Comment: Like rob mayoff: mentioned i am using a storyboard. I did drop an object to the Tab bar Controller view using the IB and then mapped the custom class in the IB to AppDelegate, but now when i press the second tab the application crashes...